# How to connect a proxy with my android emulator?

Tags: android, proxy

I tried to connect a proxy called `mitproxy` with my android emulator. After launching the proxy I got those two messages:
`Web   server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
Proxy server listening at http://*:8080`

My android emulator Wi-Fi network settings is:
`proxy host name : my laptop IP,
proxy port: 8080`

What I am always getting mitproxy is cliend connected and client disconnected always getting that no calls appears just those two repeated? Any one have a better proxy to use or an answer?

Comment: I can't see anything programming-related in your question.

Comment: yeah I know it is not a programming issue but it is more related to a developer needs right? I need to see the requests my app is doing is this wrong?

Comment: first try to connect from some other source to that proxy to check if the problem is in Android emulator or not.

Comment: good point will try to do so